# create dynamic checkbox in wordpress editor button pop-up using window manager wordpress

Tags: jquery, checkbox, wordpress

I am trying to create dynamic checkbox in tinymce wordpress editor button. below is code. can anyone help me where i am doing mistake.

```
 editor.windowManager.open({    
                title: 'Property Listing For Multiple Selection',
                 popup_css : false, // Disable TinyMCE's default popup CS

for (var n = 0; n < P_name.length; n++) {

body: [
    {
        type: 'checkbox',
        //name: 'checkboxes',
        text:"MyCheckbox",
        value:"abcll",

                 onclick: function( b ) {
                     //if(b.data.title ==vine) {
                     alert(this.text());
                     alert(this.value());
                    //}
                 },
     },

  ]

 }
  },            
 }); //window manager close
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but I'll answer anyway in the hope that it helps someone. I'm not using the Wordpress plugin, but my response should still be relevant.

Create a new tinyMCE collection, and set the collection with your data before initializing tinyMCE. Then iterate through it, prior to opening the window, rather than within window.open(). Push your iterated data to an array, you then pass this as the 'body' value.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qs5hzsh2. Click 'Delete Templates' to open the window.

Example code below:

```
var arr = [{title: 'Some title 1', id: 4},{title: 'Some title 2', id: 5}];
var collection = new tinymce.ui.Collection();
collection.set(arr);

tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    setup : function(ed) {
        var checkboxes = [];
        collection.each(function(item){
            checkboxes.push({type:"checkbox", id: item.id, text: item.title});  
        });
        ed.addButton('deletetemplate', {
            text : 'Delete Templates',
            icon: false, 
            onclick : function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Delete Templates',
                    width : 400,
                    height : 400,
                    body: checkboxes
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If this helps anyone it would be appreciated if you could upvote it :)